# sklearn algorihtm for feature importance or selection that accept nominal categorical variables without encoding them

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am looking for an algorithm that is used for feature selection or importance in sklearn. I tried decision tree classifier, but it was asking for float values. I have a mixed type dataset, it does not make sense to encode categories as numbers where there is no order. I  have like 12 datasets that are weekly datasets, I want to see which demographic features are important in each week or dataset, when including some features, the classification accuracy will improve.

Thanks,

Comment: Please see [Why do categorical variables need preprocessing in scikit-learn, compared to other tools?](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#why-do-categorical-variables-need-preprocessing-in-scikit-learn-compared-to-other-tools). `Scikit-learn` requires the conversion of categorical features into numeric values, there is no way around it. But nobody forces you to use an ordinal encoding.

Comment: Does not use numbers mislead the model and results will be different?